# MacOS - Map network drive on boot

Tags: macos, boot, automount

On my mac I'd like to move my home directory to a Synology NAS.  I'm unable to figure out how to mount the NAS drive on boot up.  My workaround is to use a local user to auto-mount the drive, but that is less than elegant.

How do I automatically mount a network drive on boot up on an mac?  I'm running 10.13.6 (macOS High Sierra).

Thanks, 
Sriram

Comment: So, it sounds like you already have the drive mapped, correct?

Comment: I can map it using the Finder.  However on reboot it has to be remapped manually.  I've added it as a map-on-login to a different user, but it means that I have to log in to the other user before I log into the main account.  Thanks, Sriram

Answer (score 2):

To map to the network drive on boot, you'll need to add it to the `Login Items` under your current user.

To do this, open the settings menu, and select `Users and Groups`. When in the window, there is the `Login Items` tab at the top. Once you're in the `Login items` tab, you can add the network drive to the list. You can do this by either dragging and dropping the mapped drive from the desktop into the list, or you can click the `+` icon and select the drive from the Finder like explorer that pops up.

By default, this will make the directory open up on your desktop at login. If you do not want that to happen, uncheck the `Hide` option.

[image]

Comment: My home directory is on the mapped drive, so the map-on-login approach will not work.  I have added the map-on-login to a different user but this means that every time the mac is rebooted I have to first log in to that account, log out, and then log into the main account.